# Are all Flutter packages free?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-dependencies

I'm starting out my journey on mobile development and decided to learn Flutter; I've come across a bunch of packages on pub.dev but some of them seem way to good to be free, and so i wanted to know if i can use them all without concern or if they require some kind of reference on the application afterwards.

I know there are some services like firebase that requires some kind of payment depending on the amount of storage you want, but I'm talking more about the front end libraries.

Comment: yes most most of the packages are free. you can fulfil all of your requirements with free packages.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the pub is free to download.  There may be restrictions on usage... please read the licenses carefully, but most everything in the pub is MIT or Apache or similar... in other words, very liberally free.

Answer (score 4):

> or if they require some kind of reference on the application afterwards.

Many of them do require that you list them in your license page of your application.

There already are functions to do this in Flutter: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showLicensePage.html

You can put a button to show this in your "About" menu in your application. Since listing the software packages you used costs you absolutely nothing, I would consider them "free".